# How to display a specific Excel Range in c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, interop

For a little windows application, I need to display a specific range of a worksheet into a container of my WPF window. This range contains shapes and also notes that have to de displayed too.

This app takes a folder of many excel files with the same format. After choosing the folder, the user selects the file and the part of the file (Part One, Part two ...) The parts don't correspond to rows or columns, it is like "D28:AA39". The selection works well, selection of range too but once my Range is selected I don't know how to display it. Datagrid doesn't seem to display shapes and notes.

The app is supposed to be used on a small screen and with a device with not awesome specs so displaying in a new Excel file isn't a viable solution. The final result is to display the range in my C# window with all the data. Those data doesn't need to be alterable, they just need to be readable. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out myself how to do it the "simplest" way. 
To make this opration i just used the [Range].CopyPicture() which allow you to copy the range as a picture in the clipboard. 
Then you save this into as a temporary file and once it is done you just have to display an Image in a container.

Hope it will help other people.